# Fatal Error: Foundation/Foundation.h: no such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, fatal-error

I'm on Windows 7 and I have this `HelloWorld.m` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSLog (@"Hello, World!");
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
}
```

And I typed this command line in the hope my code would compile:

```
gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/ -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/ -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

But it produced the error:

```
HelloWorld.m:1:34: fatal error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
```

What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `-F` flag that specifies a path to the GNUStep frameworks, most likely.

The compiler needs to no where the frameworks live to be able to find the headers contained within.

Typically, something like `-F /GNUstep/System/Library/Frameworks/` will work (bearing in mind that I've not done windows based GCC + ObjC in a long long long time).